# Python: Naive Bayes movie review

Tags: python, probability

I have a task to classify an unseen movie review into either a positive review or a negative one. I have a two folders, neg and pos, each containing 1,000 files which are movie reviews that have already been classified.

So far, what I have done is loaded the positive reviews, and I have each word stored in a dictionary along with the frequency each word occurs. I then divided each words frequency by the total amount of words in the positive folders files. I have done the same thing with the negative folder.

I am currently stuck as to where to go next. In the end I am going to have to load in an unseen review and determine if the review is positive or negative. I am not looking for any code, just guidence as to what I need to do next to achieve this. Any help is greatly appriciated, thanks!

Comment: You say "I am not looking for any code, just guidance": so post your question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE this does not seem like it is anywhere near being on-topic for Code-Review. We should get out of the habit of sending question-askers over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.

Comment: This question is a bit broad for StackOverflow. Since you currently have a few of your requirements figured out already, and now you have a remaining task that you are having difficulty with. Some advice I can give on this is to try to structure and attempt that remaining functionality you are trying to add. Then, collect your difficulties as a [mcve] and post it as a question here. That would make it on-topic and more inclined for *good* helpful answers. Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is a typical Sentiment Analysis problem, and what you've done with the reviews is called language model in (word, probability) format. I suggest you watch Professor Dan Jurafsky's video series on Sentiment Analysis as part of a Stanford course on NLP [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxPBv4Skj98). Another great practical [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nla4C-VYNEU) by Harrison Kinsley on NLTK [ a python module for NLP related tasks] will show you how to use NLTK along with Scikit-learn [a popular python module for ML tasks] to do the classification using NB classifier and many others.

Comment: Hi [ : The resource you linked to is quite interesting and helpful. Yet, I feel this answer is better suited for a comment. Just a heads up to not get downvoted while you're being sincerely helpful, especially when the question can be tagged as opnion-based.

Comment: OP is looking for "guidance" and not code as he/she described, so I pointed him/her and anyone else who might as well have his/her problem in performing simple Sentiment Analysis task to a basic, concise, yet informative set of lectures on the subject.

Comment: Absolutely [ : I said OP was looking for an opinion, not code, and that isn't allowed on SO. On SO you need to post code, in MCVE format, with the desired output and the current undesired one. I also stressed out that your contribution is quite helpful. I'm watching the lecture myself. It's just a heads up, buddy [ : Feel free to disregard it.

Answer (score 0):

The best guidance here might be the Udacity ML course... They use the excellent scikit-learn library to classify emails using Naive Bayes, specifically the Gaussian flavour of NB; this sounds exactly like the problem you have:

https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-machine-learning--ud120

If you are already comfortable with the concepts and you are happy to use SK-learn then jump straight to the docs here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#multinomial-naive-bayes

Fitting the model and then making predictions is actually trivial with SK-learn, once you have the data in the right form.